# How to calculate column from aggregated data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax

In Power BI or Excel, how would I generate a calculated column that takes an summation and works backwards to determine each row's contribution to that summation? An example is below:

Given I have YTD Sales for each date for a person, I'd like to determine on each day how much each individual's daily sales was. The data I have is (1) Date, (2) Person, (3) Sales YTD. What I'm looking for is a formula for the Calculated Daily Sales.

| Date | Person | Sales YTD | Calculated Daily Sales (formula needed) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | John | 1,000 | 1,000 |
| 1/1/2023 | Mark | 2,000 | 2,000 |
| 1/2/2023 | John | 1,000 | 0 |
| 1/2/2023 | Mark | 2,500 | 500 |
| 1/3/2023 | John | 1,000 | 0 |
| 1/3/2023 | Mark | 3,000 | 500 |
| 1/4/2023 | John | 2,500 | 1,500 |
| 1/4/2023 | Mark | 3,000 | 0 |
| 1/5/2023 | John | 3,000 | 500 |
| 1/5/2023 | Mark | 4,000 | 1,000 |

Comment: Can you explain reason of zero `0` and less than `Sales YTD` in result column?

Comment: What version of Excel?  This is easier with Excel O365.

Comment: @Harun24hr `Sales YTD` is the aggregation of all Daily Sales. In my data set, I do not have Daily Sales though, I only have Sales YTD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power BI, given that your original table contains `Date`, `Person` and `Sales YTD`, the calculation would be something like this if you wanted a calculated column to be added:

```
Daily Sales =
VAR _current_date = 'Table'[Date]
VAR _current_sales = 'Table'[Sales YTD]

VAR _previous_date =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Person] ),
        'Table'[Date] < _current_date
    )
VAR _previous_sales =
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Sales YTD] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Person] ),
        'Table'[Date] = _previous_date
    )
RETURN
    _current_sales - _previous_sales
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that:

- You do not have access to O365, which makes this easier;
- Your headers in A1:D1.

Then in Cell D2 place:

`=C2- MAX(($B$2:$B$11=B2) * ($A$2:$A$11<A2) * $C$2:$C$11)`

And then copy/fill it down.

This will work as long as the sales numbers only go up, because it assumes the maximum previous YTD sales amount is the most recent amount.  If there is the potential for the YTD sales to go down, then it gets a bit more complicated.

Also, if you are 100% certain that there will *always* be a YTD amount for every employee on every single day, you could just use yesterday's YTD for that employee.  This allows the YTD numbers to fluctuate up and down, but again requires a YTD amount be present on every day:

`=C2- SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11=B2) * ($A$2:$A$11=A2-1) * $C$2:$C$11)`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't try this as the marked solution did what I needed.